# PC as Bluetooth Airplay receiver

Tags: windows, bluetooth, airplay

Well, the title pretty much speaks for itself. I would like to stream my Mac's music to my PC over Bluetooth.
It appears this isn't supported by default (or at least my devices are reporting it's not).

Is there some way to do this? Does it require an extra application perhaps? There are a lot of solutions to do so over wifi but i would prefer bluetooth...

Comment: Just curious: Why should one prefer Bluetooth if they can have WLAN?

Comment: What's the OS of your PC?

Comment: @MaxRied: win 7 and the WLAN I'm currently on is not allowing Airplay (business kind of network, lots of limitations)

Comment: Something like this? https://superuser.com/questions/58632/can-i-use-my-pc-as-a-bluetooth-headset-for-my-mobile-phone

Comment: @MaxRied: yes, the same principle is applied. However, the mobile phone in that question has to be replaced by a mac. EDIT: the solutions on that page are not directly applicable

Comment: So your setup allows you to use your PC as a Bluetooth speaker and just want to know how to use it with your Mac?

Comment: yes, i can do the same with my iphone or ipad without a problem, i just couple them to my pc over Bluetooth and i can start streaming music to the pc. However, when coupling my mac, it only allows for setting up an ad-hoc connection on the pc, and the mac indicates it is disconnected almost instantly after coupling...

Comment: This is outdated, but might be OK for you: http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_can_i_pair_connect_bluetooth_speakers_mac_macbook/

Comment: Or better: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14217

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself.

For some reason, after pairing, you still need to manually connect.

This functionality however is completely unavailable in the preferences window and can only be accessed using the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar.
Once there you simply have to select the paired device to stream your music to and choose connect.

After doing so the mac will automatically open iTunes so you can test your newly made connection.

Note: this can only be done on the mac, there is no way to request this type of connection from the PC.